# Create folder in server with name populated from one of the field in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to create a subfolder in web server. Once the customer uploads the document and those files should be saved in folder with name that is from one of the field values from the table.

Here is my controller part

```
 public ActionResult UploadLoader(FormCollection fc, IncidentInfo model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
       if (file.ContentLength > 0)
       {
          //add function to test for file types
          // extract only the filename             
          var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
          switch (i)
          {
             case 0:
               model.File1_Filename = fileName;
               break;

             case 1:
                model.File2_Filename = fileName;
                break;
          }
          // store the file inside ~/UploadedDocs/  claim number as folder name
          var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocs/"), model.fh_claim_num + fileName);
         // this is the string you have to save in your DB
         string filepathToSave = "UploadedDocs/" + model.fh_claim_num + fileName;
         file.SaveAs(path);
```

This is not working.

My confusion is can I get the values from model. Also is it better to attach the folder name inside the directory or outside.

**Bit new to MVC please ignore if any mistake

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> should be saved in folder with name that is from one of the field values from the table

That leads me to believe you haven't created the folder yet to house the files yet. You'll need to use [`Directory.CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the directory that will house the files for that claim number before you attempt to save the file upload.

Comment: But right now the files are getting saved in UploadedDocs folder. So it means there is already directory defined right? Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Instead of all the files getting uploaded to that folder , I wanted to add a new folder with the name of claim number inside uploadeddocs folder for each cust when they upload the docs. I hope this makes sense

Comment: @Ethan Kind of makes sense. If they are being uploaded to the uploadedocs folder alone, that would lead me to believe `model.fh_claim_num` is empty or null. I'd start debugging the model values and see if indeed the anticipated values are there.

Comment: Its adding 0 at starting of the filename thats means the model.file_claim_num is empty. But it does not create a folder inside uploadeddocs! Bit Confused

Comment: @Ethan One issue, you need to use a directory separator between `model.fh_claim_num + fileName`. You can use `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocs/"), model.fh_claim_num, fileName);` which will create the path with correct separators.

Comment: I was trying to populate a field that was having null value and that was my issue. Finally i figured it out so thanks